# Changing value of div with javascript based on server variable

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I have the following div which loads a String from my web server:

```
<div id="productTitle" class="productType"><h2>{{productType}}</h2></div>
```

Depending on the type of product this page is currently displaying, {{productType}} will contain a different value, i.e. SHIRT, LEGGINGS, SKIRT, etc.

Obviously, the following will replace everything within that div with a more user-friendly title for the product type, but this only works if the number of "productType" is 1. In reality, there are 50+ potential Strings which can be generated.

```
<script>
    $( "div.productType" ).replaceWith( "<h2>American Apparel T-Shirt</h2>" );
</script>
```

My problem is that depending on the product type delivered by the server, the user-friendly title must be something else, i.e. SHIRT = "American Apparel T-Shirt", LEGGINGS = "All-Over Printed Leggings", etc.

My attempted solution:

```
function onbodyload(){
    var d1 = document.getElementById('productTitle');
    if(d1.innerHTML==='SHIRT'){
        d1.innerHTML='American Apparel T-Shirt';
    }
};
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it because the script is being executed before the "productType" variable has been loaded into the DOM?

Comment: If you run ```console.log(d1.innerHTML)``` before the if statement in the last block of code, what does it give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work

Because the innerHTML also includes an `<h2>` tag which will be part of the string you are comparing to

---

Solution using jQuery `text(function)`

```
$(function(){
   $( "#productTitle h2" ).text(function(_, existingText ){
      switch (existingText ){
         case 'SHIRT':
            return 'American Apparel T-Shirt';
            break;
         // add other cases
         default:
           return existingText; 
      }    
   });
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing this at server in `{{productType}}`? Will definitely be better for SEO

Answer (score 1):

While I believe it is possible to do the way you're doing, I think it is bad practice and you should consider, either:

- Create a new table field to save the full "user-friendly" title
- Whatever is replacing your "{{productType}}", replace with the proper name instead.

You didn't mention what is it that is replacing "{{productType}}", if you do I might be able to help you better.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, my question is how are you replacing productType with "SHIRT, LEGGINS" etc? Are you using javascript to replace it?